# Организация данных для хранения и записи в файл

Tags: c++

Как можно реализовать хранение и последующую запись/чтение из файла данных типа:

> Маленький дом-> 1 дверь, 5 окон
> Большой дом -> 15 дверей, 600 окон

Кол-во домов неограниченно для ввода, данные - только двери и окна.

Managed C++. Использовать структуру? Но если создать структуру подобного типа, то как ее потом объявлять, если не знаешь какой дом будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Динамическое выделение памяти под структуры и другие типы данных можно выполнить в С++ при помощи функций malloc() или calloc() или оператора new (объекты - только им). Ими также можно создавать массивы произвольного размера. Подробнее смотри книжки по С++ и Google.

Comment: Хорошо. Наглядный пример, мой прошлый вопрос. Вы отвечали на него. Про здания и офисы:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/51458/структура-данных-с-упорядоченным-списком-с-последующим-сохранением-в-файл

Вопрос оттуда сюда, я прокомментировал ниже:
"Я вспомнил в чем у меня была загвоздка, почему я не сразу взял структуры. Данные: офис, завод динамические. Мне неизвестно сколько этих мест будет. Как быть?"

Comment: Так я об этом здесь и пишу. Т.е. о том, как динамически выделять память под структуры и  их массивы (т.е.создавать их, по-простому). Я дал направление, куда копать. Дальше уж сами немного потрудитесь. Там ничего сложного нет.

Comment: malloc и callloc - это C-style

Comment: Спасибо, @Андрей, буду знать

Answer (score 0):

а кто мешает сделать двери и окна массивами? В этом случае никаких проблем с хранением.

```
struct House {
    vector<Door> doors;
    vector<Window> windows;
};
```

(я не настолько хорошо знаю Managed c++, поэтому не могу сказать, как там точно делать массивы или что то подобное).

Comment: Не совсем понял вашу идею. Моя проблема в том, что этими данными необходимо легко оперировать для записи и чтения из файла. У меня неизвестно какое кол-во домов будет? В вашем случае (со структурой) мне все равно нужно будет объявлять struct House Big; Struct House Little; и т.д. я же не могу динамически присваивает имена структурам.

Comment: @Maxim Droy определитесь с тем, что Вам дают на вход, и что Вы хотите хранить/с чем хотите оперировать

PS вообще, вопрос сформулирован непонятно

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял что требуется, то нужно использовать структуру вроде этой:

```
struct House {
BOOL IsBig;
int DoorsCount;
int WindowCount;
}
```

и, сооветственно, заполнять свойство IsBig = TRUE для больших домов, FALSE для маленьких
Записывать в файл (и читать из файла) нужно массив таких структур.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать наследование:

```
struct house
{
protected:
    int Doors, int Windows; /* или массивы/вектора структур Door, Window, если надо хранить данные о дверях и окнах */
}

struct small_house : house
{}

struct big_house : house
{}
```

На заметку struct{...} в C++ тоже самое, что и  class {public: ...}

Comment: Вы меня не так понимаете. Какой дом вводит пользователь: он может быть не только большой или маленький. Он может еще быть красным, некрасивым и т.д. я не знаю каким он может быть в будущем. Это будет браться из текстбокса благодаря пользователю. А потом, введя название дома он может уже вводит кол-во окон и дверей к нему.

Comment: @Maxim Droy что мешает Вам сначала осознать, каким будет дом, а потом объявить переменную? И @ganouver, по-моему, прав - размер дома спокойно может быть его свойством (как цвет, красота и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Максим, из Ваших комментариев я понял (наверное понял), что на самом деле у Вас есть несколько (это про офисы, фабрики ...) объектов и с каждым связан список свойств, задаваемых пользователем (возможно из множества предопределенных).

Боюсь, что предлагаемые Вам структуры данных ("жесткие") здесь не очень подходят. Видимо Вам надо оперировать списками объектов, каждый из которых имеет (один или несколько) списков свойств вида имя-свойства:значение.

Могу предположить, что в файл придется перед таким объектом помещать его некое описание, которым надо пользоваться при чтении.

Если это предложение Вам кажется интересным, то можно попробовать спроектировать такую конструкцию.

Comment: Да это у него учебное задание. Он мне это в обсуждении предыдущего вопроса написал.